# Exclude files while using Ember-CLI testem

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, testem

I am trying to run my tests using Ember-CLI - Testem. 
Ember-CLI uses tests/index.html and not the usual testem.json config for testing.

Is there any way I can exclude certain files from being built into app.js?

Usecase : I have some js files where I inject some dependencies. These dependencies are different during the testing environment. I would like to ignore these files and inject the dependencies from my test-injectors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering in the context of an ember application using ember-cli 1.13.8 and  ember 2.1.
ember-cli does use `testem.json` unless you pass another test configuration file via `ember test -c path/to/testem.json`. Though, not all options from testem.json are integrated into ember-cli's test process.

To exclude trees, checkout:
[ember-cli exclude a directory beneath "tests" from being watched by "ember serve"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27514587/ember-cli-exclude-a-directory-beneath-tests-from-being-watched-by-ember-serve)

For ignoring specific files in `tests`, you can rename files so that they do not match the pattern embedded into ember-cli-test-loader:
https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-test-loader/blob/master/test-loader.js#L38-L40