# ember-cli exclude a directory beneath "tests" from being watched by "ember serve"

Tags: ember-cli

Is there a way to exclude a subdirectory of "tests" from being watched by ember serve?

ex. I have a dir under "tests" called "selenium".

If 'ember serve' is running and I do "echo xyz > bam" in the selenium folder,

the ember serve console will output "file changed selenium/bam" and rebuild the app.

I would like to understand if there is a way to  exclude the entire selenium dir without moving it out of the tests folder ( even though for now I am moving the dir)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### either:

You can use [broccoli-unwatched-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/broccoli-unwatched-tree).

Just add `var seleniumTree = new UnwatchedTree('tests/selenium');` to your Brocfile.js before you add that tree to your application with `module.exports = app.toTree(seleniumTree);`

> You can continue to use this tree just like any of the others, but due to the way it is implemented the standard Broccoli::Watcher class will not check it for file changes.

### or:

You could also implement this functionality yourself by adding an object that exports the read() and cleanup() functions that are expected by the broccoli watcher, leaving the cleanup() function empty as is done for [broccoli-bower](https://github.com/joliss/broccoli-bower/blob/ea0eec5c5fa736dc3744f3a7bb0b304b7ac9976e/index.js#L10-L12).

```js
// Almost the same as using a plain string for a tree; but unlike a plain
// string, Broccoli won't watch this
function UnwatchedTree (dir) { this.dir = dir }
UnwatchedTree.prototype.read = function (readTree) { return this.dir }
UnwatchedTree.prototype.cleanup = function () { }
```